X2GO remote desktop with XFCE doesn't refresh the screen
I have Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on a VPS with a public IP and installed the X2GO with XFCE on it remotely via SSH.
It connects successfully, but the problem is it doesn't refresh the screen properly as you can see in the image below:


Something you may want to address with the people that make the app.

It's a known issue and is discussed here.
To fix the issue I created a file named 98xfwm4-no_compositing inside /etc/X11/Xsession.d/ directory, then added the following line to it:
/usr/bin/xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/use_compositing -s false
